# Deleting rows based of a condition Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete rows when a condition when is met:
I need to drop any value that is less than zero in specific column.

For instance,I import a csv file:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('Surface_Time_PS.csv') 
df.drop_duplicates(subset='DEPTH',keep='first',inplace=True) #DROP ANY DUPLICATION IN DEPTH 

df['Difference1']=df['DEPTH(ft)'].diff()
df['Difference1']

for x in "df.Difference1":
    if [df['Difference1'].diff() < 0]:
        df.drop(df[df['Difference1'].diff() < 0].index, inplace=False)           #FUNCTION WHERE IS THE DIFF IN DEPTH IS MUST BE POSITIVE OTHER WISE DROP THE row
    else:
        df
```

after running this code, I get rid of most of the row with negative value in Difference1 dropped. But still I have few negative value.

I want the code to repeat the process until the column has only positive values

Comment: isn't `df.drop(df['Difference1']<0)` enough?

Comment: You can use boolean indexing, df[df.Difference1 >=0] or df[~(df.Difference1 < 0)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove for loop statement and put this line below:

```
df.drop(df[df['Difference1'] < 0].index, inplace=True)
```